# Extension bug after installation

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, extensions

After installing a module, it appears in my back office but when I click on it, I get this message that appears:

[image: Extension bug]

Comment: It seems that table associated with the module is not there. Have you run the necessary commands ?

Comment: @Tanmay I run 2 commands : php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: It seems table is not created. Which command you have executed?

Comment: @PrashantValanda `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: try removing generated and run di:compile then deploy it will solve ur issue. i can see something related to interception in that big error log since am rplyimg from phone so i cant see the complete log

Answer (score 1):

Go to Db open table `setup_module` delete row of just installed extension name from table.

Then run below command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: don't you think compilation command is also needs to be run ?

Comment: If your environment in production mode then compilation command require otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the extension `DPDFrance_ShippingM2` module. **A table dpd_option is created from this extension that does not do not exist at your database that why you are getting error**.

First, You have to disable that extension `php bin/magento module:disable DPDFrance_ShippingM2` and after that run extension `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

You have to ci